# Remove duplicates from only one dataframe spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes.

**df1:**

```
|AusID|ProjectId|
+-----+----------
|529  |20034    |
|973  |20035    |
|521  |20034    |
|543  |20035    |
```

**df2:**

```
|AusID|ProjectId|
+-----+----------
|529  |20124    |
|876  |20123    |
|521  |20234    |
|982  |21235    |
```

Both dataframes have some common **AusID**, but I want to remove the duplicates from only **df2** where **AusID** is same, without modifying **df1**. the resulting **df2** should be:

```
|AusID|ProjectId|
+-----+----------
|876  |20123    |
|982  |21235    |
```

I tried the following approach, by assigning tags, but It didn't work:

```
  val sn = df1.withColumn("label", lit("df1"))
    val pd = df2.withColumn("label", lit("df2"))

    val u = sn.union(pd)
    val du = u.dropDuplicates("AusID")
    val f = du.filter(col("label") === "df1")
```

It would be great if someone can give some hint.